# Django shopping app?

Tags: django, django-models, shopping-cart

We are developing a django app for several restaurants, it's like a shopping chart.

We need the restaurant admins to be able to create their own restaurants, menus and products, and clients must be able to browse the menus and choose the products and confirm their delivery, like a shopping app, which is the best approach? Are there django apps/snippets that simplifies this task ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a great starting point for django addons: http://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/DjangoResources

Unfortunately there's only one link for "shopping carts" in there ([Satchmo](http://www.satchmoproject.com/)), it doesn't mention [django-cart](http://code.google.com/p/django-cart/) (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/490439/django-cart-or-satchmo)) or [DJWarehouse](http://demo.djwarehouse.org/).

Personally, I rolled my own. Simple shopping carts really don't take that long to implement. If your needs are more complex then Satchmo might be the way to go.